# Setting shadow with CSS for the whole HTML table column

Tags: html, css

How do I set shadow for the whole HTML table column consisting of multiple rows?

Setting `box-shadow` on `col` doesn't have effect, while setting `box-shadow` on `td` adds shadows around each `td`, so it looks like a border around each cell instead of a single border around the whole column.

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>
        <h2>...</h2>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h2>...</h2>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h2>...</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you try this? https://gist.github.com/ocean90/1268328/21fa1d6f2563a950bdfca737abc95eb430cea238 Target the first and last element on the column to have that specific shadow so that it looks like the shadow is applied to the whole column.

Comment: would a gradient to fake a shadow would do the job ? https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOYeNjP background is about the only style you can add through the col element

Answer (score 1):

comment turned into answer if it gives any visibility or ideas ..

> would a gradient to fake a shadow would do the job ? http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/gOYeNjP background is about the only style you can add through the col element

the shadow is average 3px , update the gradients *stop/start values and colors* to your needs .

```css
table {
border-spacing: 4px 0 ;
  margin:1em auto;

}
th,td {
  padding:1em 2em;/* demo */
}
col {
background:
  linear-gradient(to bottom, white 0, transparent 3px, transparent 3px),
  linear-gradient(to top, white 0, transparent 3px, transparent 3px),
  linear-gradient(to left, white , gray 3px, transparent 3px ),
  linear-gradient(to right,white , gray 3px, transparent 3px ),
  linear-gradient(to top, white , gray 3px, transparent 3px ),
  linear-gradient(to bottom, white , gray 3px, transparent 3px ) yellow
  }
  col:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:tomato;
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>....</th>
      <th>
        <h2>...</h2>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h2>...</h2>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h2>...</h2>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
      <td>...</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still cannot get it right in the corners and when I specify a different background color for some rows.  I'll probably have to switch to Flexbox tables.